# Passing boolean args to a fixture

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I am trying to write a test that uses a fixture `my_fixture` I am hoping I could pass parameters to the fixture. Is it possible? Here is what I am thinking:

```
@pytest.fixtures(scope="session", autouse=True, args]
def my_fixture(another_fixture):
  # Do something
  anoter_fixture.do_sth()
  foo = Foo()
  yield
  foo.cleanup(*args)


@pytest.mark.parametrize('arg', [arg1=False, arg2=True])
def my_test(my_fixture)
  # Do x, y, z
  my_fixture.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can achieve this using [indirect parametrization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/parametrize.html#deferring-the-setup-of-parametrized-resources). This means that you provide the parameters in `mark.parametrize` which are available in the fixture `request` fixture.
In your case, something like this might work:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True]
def my_fixture(request, another_fixture):
  # get the provided parameter, provide a default value if not given
  arg = request.param if hasattr(request, "param") else False
  # use it (not sure where you need it)
  another_fixture.do_sth(arg)
  foo = Foo()
  yield
  foo.cleanup(arg)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('my_fixture', [False, True], indirect=True)
def my_test(my_fixture)
  my_fixture.run()
```

This will create 2 tests with the `arg` parameter set to `True` and `False`, respectively.